# Issues with grep and get a count of a string in a loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of search strings in a file (File1) and a content file (File2). I am trying to loop through all the search strings within File1 and get a count of each of the search string within File2 and output it - I want to automate this and make it generic so I can search through multiple content files. However, I dont seem to be able to get the exact count when I execute this loop. **I get a "0" count for each of the strings although I have those strings in the file.** Unable to figure out what I am doing wrong and can use some help !

**Below is the script I came up with:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    count=$(echo cat "$2" | grep -c "$line")
    echo "$count - $line"
done < "$1"
```

**Command I am using to run this script:**

```
./scanscript.sh File1.log File2.log
```

**I say this since I searched this command separately and get the right value. This command works by itself but I want to put this in a loop**

```
cat File2.log | grep -c "Search String"
```

**Sample Data for File 1 (Search Strings):**

```
/SERVER_NAME/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/
/SERVER_NAME3/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/
```

**Sample Data for File 2 (Content File):**

```
./SERVER_NAME/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/test.test_proc.sql:29:     
./SERVER_NAME2/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/test.test_proc.sql:100:       
./SERVER_NAME3/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/test.test_proc.sql:143:       
./SERVER_NAME4/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/test.test_proc.sql:223:       
./SERVER_NAME5/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/test.test_proc.sql:5589:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
count=$(echo cat "$2" | grep -c "$line")
```

That should be changed to:

```
count=$(grep -Fc "$line" "$2")
```

Also note `-F` is to be used for fixed string search instead of regex search.

---

**Full code:**

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    count=$(grep -Fc "$line" "$2");
    echo "$count - $line";
done < "$1"
```

Run it as:

```
./scanscript.sh File1.log File2.log
```

**Output:**

```
1 - /SERVER_NAME/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/
1 - /SERVER_NAME3/Root/DEV/Database/NJ-CONTENT/Procs/
```

Comment: Still doesnt seem to help ! Is this because I have a '/' in my content file  - ex: "SERVER/Search String/xxxxx/yyyy" and I am searching for "Search String".

Comment: count=$(grep -Fc "$line" "$2") - doesnt help either ! Still get a 0

Comment: Added the test data to the question - pls check.

Comment: Not sure why but it still doesnt work for me. Does it work for you with the test data ?

Comment: Yes I have tested it already with your sample data. Can you check input data by using `cat -A file` and make sure you don't see `^M` in the end of line. If you get then convert it to Unix file first by using `dos2unix` command.

Comment: Wow ! that worked. thank you @Anubhava. That was the problem and glad you caught it.....Appreciate your help buddy !